# percentage tags in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Following along on a tutorial in MVC, would you tell me the alternative to this in a ASPX page

```
<div>
    <%=ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>
</div>
```

In a **cshtml** page, the default view type in MVC 4 on VS2013. When I try the above, the literal meaning is displayed. i.e. `ViewData["CurrentTime"]` instead of the value DateTime.now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you using a `cshtml`. You are working with Razor engine.

In Razor engine, You need to use `@` like

```
@ViewData["CurrentTime"]
```

`<%=ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>` is a ASP.Net engine code

Answer (score 4):

There are two engines in MVC: Razor and ASP.NET WebForms.

`.cshtml` filles are the files using Razor engine and this is a default engine of ASP.NET MVC from the third version.

The syntax you are using would work with the old WebForms engine.

So you should write:

```
@ViewData["CurrentTime"]
```

in case you use ViewData or

```
@ViewBag.CurrentTime
```

in case you use ViewBag which is more common when using Razor view engine and in general newer version of ASP.NET MVC .

Comment: +1. Or even better to pass information via strongly typed model and use `@Model.CurrentTime`